# How to convert Microsoft sql 7 database to Microsoft sql 2008 database?

Tags: database, sql-server

Is it possible to convert an Microsoft SQL 7 database into Microsoft SQL 2008?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Migrating a Database can include

1. Upgrading the server components (engine, dts packages, Sql jobs)
2. Database structure
3. Routines (stored procedures, views, etc)

depending on if you just need the data and its schema or you need everthing your options will be different

In any case from what I gather MS only supports skipping one version but not two. This means you'll need an intermediate step of upgrading to 2000 or 2005 before you can upgrade to 2008.

these guides will help you figure out what to do

[upgrading to 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144245(v=SQL.90).aspx)

[upgrading to 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677622(v=SQL.100).aspx)

Comment: thanks, its ok now, I just restored a backup of the database from sql 7 using server management studio.